What are the design considerations for the ailerons of the Pilatus PC7 Mk II?
The ailerons trailing edge is not in line with the adjacent inboard wing TE, jutting out by few cm:

What are the design considerations?

That's an aileron trim tab and/or servo tab. I looks to me a bit of chord was added after development to improve the roll rate while leaving the inboard fixed TE, under which is a split fowler flap, alone.
